# Absolute positioning with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am adding a list of images to my site with two images fading on hover. For some reason though, it ignores the "col-md-3 col-sm-3" classes and goes out of the columns. How can I fix this?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <figure class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 client-item">
            <div class="fadehover">
                <img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="images/clients/aersale.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="top img-responsive thumbnail" src="images/clients/aersale-grayscale.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
    </figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clients-list {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.client-item {
  margin-left:  10px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  position:     relative;
}

.fadehover {
  position: relative;
 /* height: 257px; */
}

.fadehover img {
   position:           absolute;
   left:               0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:    opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition:      opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   transition:         opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.fadehover img.top:hover {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution would be to only absolutely position one `img` element.. in this case, `.top`:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TLde7/)

```
.fadehover img.top {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

In doing so, the parent element, `.col-md-3.col-sm-3` will no longer collapse upon itself because only one child element is absolutely positioned. In this instance, the other `img` element will define the dimensions of the parent because it is still in the document flow - unlike the absolutely positioned one.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help but unfortunately this won't work. I added the Bootstrap css to your jsfiddle so you can see whats going on. http://jsfiddle.net/TLde7/

Comment: @user3256132 Simple fix. Just reverse the order of the `img` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/4rAp8/